# Is it possible to reorder my places in Nautilus?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, places

I just upgraded to the latest LTS, and now I'm setting things up for the next couple of years.

I know this is petty:  is it possible to reorder my Places in this new Nautilus?  I am used to `File System` being first in the list, and `Downloads` being last (above the trash).  It just makes more sense to me.

I've snooped around the dconf, and a few of the tweak tools, to no avail.

[image: reordering places]

Comment: No, those bookmarks are hardcoded in Nautilus, you'll have to edit the source and compile it.

Comment: Only the user-defined can currently be edited / dragged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

1) User 'Bookmarks' can be reordered, but other items can't be reordered.

But:

2) You can edit the nautilus source code to reorder the item's addition to the list, it would be a pretty easy edit to simply change the order of the lines that add the sections in.

Good luck!